# automatically deleting non verified users after some time

Tags: users, cron, advertising

By default Drupal requires an e-mail verification when a visitor creates an account. Is it possible to automatically delete all user accounts which are not verified after a month or so?

Would it be a good idea for Drupal Commerce websites?